# How to initialize Twitter bootstrap form-helper datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, form-helpers

I've been searching the internet on how to initialize a datepicker twitter bootstrap form helper, but I cant seem to find a tutorial for it. I already have the datepicker.js embeded, but I don't know how to initialize the js to  the textbox I want it. How do I initialize the datepicker plugin?

EDIT:

I have added the text box for my datepicker:

```
        <div class="bfh-datepicker">
        <input  id="datepickers" type="text" class="datepicker">
        </div>
```

This is how I'm currently initializing it(not working)

```
$('#datepickers').bfhdatepicker('toggle');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in your code is fine.  Since you mentioned about `datepicker.js embeded` I'm giving my thoughts.

There is no need of `datepicker.js` to be embedded separately because **`bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js`** will take care of it(that the specialty of bfh).

Following the files are needed for *Twitter bootstrap form helper*.

> 1. bootstrap.min.css **v3.0.0**
> 2. bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css
> 3. jQuery library **v1.10.2**
> 4. bootstrap.min.js **v3.0.0**
> 5. bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js

See its working in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/5qy5w/1/)

Here is a official reference from [whats to be included?](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/gettingstarted/)

```
BootstrapFormHelpers/
|--- dist/
|    |--- css/
|         |--- bootstrap-formhelpers.css
|         |--- bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css
|    |--- img/
|         |--- bootstrap-formhelpers-countries.flags.png
|         |--- bootstrap-formhelpers-currencies.flags.png
|         |--- bootstrap-formhelpers-googlefonts.png
|    |--- js/
|         |--- bootstrap-formhelpers.js
|         |--- bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js
```